# How to include Winpcap to Qt creator?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I tried to use different combination in .pro file but always get these errors :

```
error: C2065: 'PCAP_SRC_IF_STRING' : undeclared identifier
error: C3861: 'pcap_findalldevs_ex': identifier not found
```

Here is my .pro file :

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = snif_del
TEMPLATE = app

LIBS += WS2_32.lib
INCLUDEPATH += D:/libs/WpdPack/Include
LIBS += -L D:/libs/WpdPack/Lib/ -lwpcap -lpacket

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

Also i added `#include "pcap.h"` to my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your .pro file should look like this:

```
INCLUDEPATH += D:/libs/WpdPack/Include
LIBS += "-LD:/libs/WpdPack/Lib" -lwpcap -lws2_32
```

If your program uses Win32 specific functions of WinPcap, add

```
DEFINES += WPCAP
```

If your program uses the remote capture capabilities of WinPcap, add

```
DEFINES += HAVE_REMOTE
```

In your code you should add

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <pcap.h>
```

Comment: No. This didn't help. And also why i need c++11?

Comment: I solved problem with adding DEFINES += HAVE_REMOTE to my .pro file. It's strangely that informations missing about this in all guiedes i've seen.